# npm warn:No README data WARN ,warn: homepage field must start with a protocal

Tags: node.js, d3.js

When I follow steps on "Data visualization with D3.js", I meet some problems. 
When i create a folder where has a file named `package.json` which contains:

```
{ 

            "name": "d3-project-template", 

            "version":  "0.1.0", 

            "description":  "Ready to go d3 data visualization project temple",

            "keywords":["data visualization","d3"],

            "homepage": "<project home page>",

            "author": {"name":"your name","url":"your url"},

            "repository":{"type":"git","url":"source repo url"},

            "dependencies":{"d3":"3.x"},

            "devDependencies": {"uglify-js": "2.x" }

          }
```

and when I get into the folder and type the command `npm install`:

```
pri17@pri17-Lenovo-V480:~$ sudo su

[sudo] password for pri17: 

root@pri17-Lenovo-V480:/home/pri17# cd /home/pri17/文档/D3-pro

root@pri17-Lenovo-V480:/home/pri17/文档/D3-pro# npm install

npm WARN package.json d3-project-template@0.1.0 No README data

npm WARN package.json d3-project-template@0.1.0 homepage field must start with a protocol.
```

Comment: Try replacing `"homepage": "..."` with `"homepage": "http://website.com"`.

Comment: Glad to help, I reposted my comment as an answer so you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter to `"homepage"` needs to actually start with a protocol, e.g. `"http"`. Try replacing what you currently have for the `"homepage"` with something like this:

```
"homepage": "http://website.com"
```